# Citation for minibatch processing?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references

Is there a paper which first introduced minibatching?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a tricky question to answer as mini-batch optimisation seems like a natural idea and it might be called something different in different communities. The earliest reference I could easily find is the following:

> Bertsekas, Dimitri P. "Incremental least squares methods and the
>   extended Kalman filter." SIAM Journal on Optimization 6.3 (1996):
>   807-822.

But I would be surprised if the idea wasn't used before then, given the Robbins and Monro paper on stochastic gradient descent came out in 1951.

Comment: Thanks for the response!